# React Native: Find substring in text, and change style programmatically

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Forgive me if I'm missing something standard here, as React isn't my default javascript dev tool. This seems like something that should fairly easily obtainable though so I figured I should ask. Is it possible, and if so how can I find a **substring**, and then change the style of that **substring** in React Native?

#### Example:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>
                {this.state.myText}
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
}

componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let newStr = this.state.myText.replace('green',  '<Text style={{ color: "green" }}>green</Text>');
        this.setState({ myText: newStr });
    },
    3000)
}
```

But clearly you can't dynamically add a Text component in order to style a substring this way. What is the proper method?

#### Edit:

I've been looking into this more, and if I'm not mistaken... I have to make an entire array of subcomponents, keep track of the subcomponents, and then dynamically add/remove text components to this array along with the strings if I simply want to change the color of text? Someone please tell me React is not this flawed in this aspect...

#### Final code used:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>
            {this.state.textItems.map(item => (
              <Text style={{ color: item === 'green' ? 'green' : 'black' }}>{item}</Text>
            ))}
          </Text>
        </View>
    );
}

componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ textItems: this.state.textItems[0].split((/(green)/)) });
    },
    3000)
}
```

Comment: Text modules cannot be parents. Unable to insert text into text module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an array which contains strings or objects (*if you want to customize it deeper, not only it's color*), and then map it into array of `Text` components. Here is the sample code.

```
class Sample extends Component {
  // You can manipulate this items array, using setState
  state = {
    items: ['black', 'green', 'red']
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Text>
        {textItems.map(item => (
          <Text style={{ color: item }}>{item}</Text>
        ))}
      </Text>
    );
  }
}
```

the result will be like this

[image]

Comment: I really don't want to believe that this is what must be done, but everything I've read says it is and this is the **only** way to change a substring's style. Thank you.

Comment: it seems awkward at first, but you will be comfortable with react. You're welcome! @Z.Bagley

Answer (score 0):

You should do this by using styles. There are many ways but this is one:

```
constructor(){
  this.state = {color: "black", myText: "hello"};
}
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text style={{color: this.state.color}}>
                {this.state.myText}
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
}

componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ color: "green" });
    },
    3000)
}
```

Comment: Looking to change part of the main string's color on search (substring), not the entire string.

Comment: @Z.Bagley so you have a search box and want to change the color of the text that exactly matches the search box's text?

Comment: I have text that is pulled dynamically from various locations (imagine a paragraph from a book, or a webpage) and want to identify all occurrences of a specific word (also found programmatically, dynamically). The answer I accepted does what I was looking for, but I'm always open to other suggestions.

Comment: @Z.Bagley forgive me but I don't see how that answer supports dynamic color change depending on other text. I don't have an answer for you but I'm interested to see what you work out

Comment: Feel free to check out my updated answer for the final code I used. This splits out the 'green' and styles it depending on the text. In my real use case, I will style it depending on more complex logic but the general idea remains.